# Datatables direct insertion of colvis button

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using Datatables and have the colvis button working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/datatables.min.js"></script>

datatable = $('.datatableclass').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: ['excelHtml5','colvis']
});
```

But I'm trying to place the colvis button somewhere else - alongside the rest of my buttons rather than using the default datatables buttons group.

This is what I have tried:

```
<script>
datatable = $('.datatableclass').DataTable( {
  buttons: ['excelHtml5','colvis']
});

datatable.buttons('.buttons-colvis').container().appendTo( $('#colvis-div') );
</script>
...
<div id="colvis-div"></div>
```

This works, but includes the entire button group (export + colvis buttons). I only want to show the colvis button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Buttons API to handle this. Here is one way:

First create your Excel button in the usual way, but do not create the `colvis` button:

```js
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: ['excelHtml5']
} );
```

Then use the API to create the `colvis` button:

```js
new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
  name: 'colvis-button',
  buttons: ['colvis']
} );

table.buttons(1, null).container().appendTo( $('#colvis-div') );
```

In the above snippet, the `buttons(1, null)` selector is [documented here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons()). The `1` refers to the second (zero-indexed) button group that was created.

There are [additional ways](https://datatables.net/reference/type/button-group-selector) to select the required group, if you don't want to use its index. So, for example, using the name will also work:

```js
table.buttons('colvis-button', null).container().appendTo( $('#colvis-div') );
```

In my case, the end result is this, with the colvis div added below the table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I understand now. That did the trick.